# Cloning Dev environment for minimum configuration fuss.

Tags: git, virtual-machine, development-environment

I've been using a single user profile since year dot for all dev / personal / etc, and it's been ok.  Recently I've spent a lot of time playing with new / different techs and spending vast amounts of time resolving conflicts, setting up configurations and so on.

There must be an easier way...cue lightbulb moment.

I think if I were to set up a virtual machine solely for dev purposes it would help solve my problem, I could configure once and then if I needed a different environment then I could clone the vm, update and move on.  No mess involved.  I suspect for the vast majority of you this may be common practice.
I'm using OSX and wondering if I can still have a shared pool of resources.  I'd like to keep my tools and res folder of my main account and allow the vms to access it to save multiple downloads.

I guess I'm hunting for best practices and solutions, workflows etc.  Is this a good idea?

-I've not really played with vms before other than to install(and then not use) win via parallel.

Comment: Check out [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/).

Comment: I've a docker workshop booked in a couple of weeks. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/). As to where to store the tools: it is more a matter of personal taste I guess. You can have all your machines share a folder with your host system where you keep all resources in one place. It can be a good idea to isolate them within the VMs because you may end up with different versions in different VMs because of different dependencies.. and try to store that in one shared folder.

It makes sense to backup your virtual machines on an external drive once set up. I use this to keep the headache away for the times my pc breaks. Just get another one, install vm-player and start the vm from my external drive.

Comment: thanks for that!  I had a scare before wiring the post as power went and the 'beast' wouldn't power on, it's at time like hat you think GAAAAAh, why no backup for over a day/week/...month.  Vagrant looks good, I never thought to look for a manager of sorts.  Reading through docs and likely to download and install.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes those are the moments.. having a VM ready to work in really calms you down ;)